# Web Loader Stress Test

Tags: html

i have constructed a web loader which loads a URL and displays the loading time.
my question is, how do i add virtual users in this site to perform multiple user testing simultaneously to stress test the selected URL.

```
<html>
<head> 
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
        function pageloadingtime()
        { 
            afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
            seconds = (afterload-beforeload)/1000;
            document.getElementById("loadingtime").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>(You Page Load took " + seconds + " second(s).)</font>";
        }
    </script>
    <title>load time</title>
</head>

<body>   
    <div id="loadingtime"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        function Reload() {
            beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();
            var f = document.getElementById('iFrame');
            f.src = f.src;
        }    
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitStuff(){
            document.getElementById('iFrame').src = 'http://' + document.theForm.url.value;
            return false ;
        }
    </script>
    <form name="theForm" method="post" onsubmit="return submitStuff();">
        <input name="url" value="" >
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit/Refresh" onclick="Reload();">
    </form>
    <iframe id="iFrame" width="1320" height="540" src="http://www.default.com" onload="pageloadingtime();"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you in a position to use a third party stress-testing tool? See the answers to this question if so... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340564/best-way-to-stress-test-a-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some software to run the stress test against the page.  I would suggest Selenium - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/.  It's quite easy to setup and use.  It will certainly do what you need.

Comment: Selenium is a great tool, but I don't think I would ever suggest that it is easy to setup or use.

Comment: @RichardEv - You're right about the full blown product, the Firefox addon may be the "easy" way: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/.

Comment: yes there are many software, but i would like to learn to construct it manually.. :D

Comment: @Dhinesh I think that is beyond the scope of this forum.  You're talking about building a multi-threaded stress test tool from scratch.  Probably better to use an existing one unless you have a compelling reason to reinvent the wheel.